# Subtracting a vector from each element in a "matrix of vectors along 3rd dimension"

Tags: r

As an analogy, consider the colors of pixels in an image. Suppose we have a 3D array representing the red, green and blue channels of an image in matrices stacked along dimension 3. What is the simplest way to "subtract a color" (represented by a vector of length 3) from this entire image, in the sense that the color's red component is subtracted from the red channel, the green component from the green channel, and the blue component from the blue channel?

Given image A and color v, we can do:

```
for(i : 1:3){
    A[,,i] <- A[,,i] - v[i]
}
```

or

```
A - array(rep(v,each=length(A[,,1])),dim(A))
```

What is the best way to do this? If there is a function like `row` and `col` but for the 3rd dimension (say `level`) then I could simply do

```
A - v[level(A)]
```

Is there such a function?

Comment: See `?slice.index`; `A - v[slice.index(A, 3)]`

Comment: @alexis_laz Perfect. Can you put that into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent or `row/col` for `dim() > 2` is `?slice.index`:

```
#with lmo's example
temp - (1:3)[slice.index(temp, 3)]
```

Like `row/col`, it creates an integer array of equal "dim" as input which can be more memory inefficient than a `for` loop.

And a benchmark for the record:

```
f1 = function(x, v)
{
    for(k in seq_len(dim(x)[3])) x[, , k] = x[, , k] - v[[k]]
    return(x)
}

f2 = function(x, v) sweep(x, 3, v)

f3 = function(x, v) x - v[slice.index(x, 3)]

set.seed(911); ARR = array(runif(11), c(300, 300, 300)); V = sample(300)

system.time({ ans1 = f1(ARR, V) })
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.91    0.19    1.09 
system.time({ ans2 = f2(ARR, V) })
#   user  system elapsed 
#   1.20    0.06    1.26 
system.time({ ans3 = f3(ARR, V) })
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.47    0.14    0.61 

identical(ans1, ans2)
#[1] TRUE
identical(ans2, ans3)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Take look at `sweep`. It will do what you want and a lot more:

```
temp <- array(rep(c(1:3), each=25), dim=c(5, 5, 3))
# subtract 1 from matrix [,,1], 2 from matrix [,,2], 3 from matrix [,,3]
sweep(temp, 3, 1:3)
```